# Run hive queries on empty dataframe using pyspark

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, pyspark, hive

I want to test my complex hive queries beforehand by executing on empty dataframes using pyspark or pandas. How can I do this. I don't want to create hive connection just mocking tables as df and then execute query on them